# Recommended torque

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fasteners

I am working on an assembly where I have various screws, mainly metal on metal fastening.
Where can I find a realiable source for recommended torque settings based on screw size, screw material and fastening surfaces materials?
I tried reading on the Machniery's Handbook but I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks,
JL

Comment: Hi, it's unclear to me, if you are asking for how much torque you need to tighten the screws or how much those can endure before failure ?

Comment: How much torque I need to tighten the screws.

Comment: Then can you provide us the coefficient of friction between any pairs, the size, length diameter, pitch, your norming system and ... . Your bio says you live in Canada, so i assume your norming system is also Canadian, i'm not sure if i can help! I work in different norming system, but hopefully someone else would contribute, anyway without those information nobody can help.